# Powershell script to import CSV to AD

Tags: active-directory, csv, powershell-v3.0

In attempts to automate a few things, I've come across a stumbling block with an import script for AD.

A part of the script contains:

```
New-ADUser -Name $Name –GivenName $Person.givenName –Surname $Person.sn –DisplayName $Name –SamAccountName $Username -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory $HDrive
```

The issue here is the **-HomeDirectory $HDrive**.

The variable **$HDrive="\data\Staff Homedrives\"**

How can i add %username% to the end of the HomeDirectory path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$UserName` is the username, then:

```
$Hdrive = "\data\Staff Homedrives\$UserName"
```

Should do it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for helping the novice powershell user!